# R: How to code new variable based on grouped variable and conditioned on earlier row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset from organ transplants.  The data are organized by donor and I'm looking at lungs - so each donor has two lungs.  The data are arranged as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(
  ~donor_id, ~sequence, ~organ_placed,
  1, 5, "L",
  1, 10, "R",
  2, 13, "B",
  3, 4, "L",
  3,69,NA,
  3,70,NA,
  3,71,NA,
  3, 72, NA,
)
```

- `donor_id` = the donor id
- `sequence` = the number of the donor offer.  I.e. it goes to person 1, then 2, then 3...and so on.
- `organ_placed` = if the organ is a match, the organ placed is listed. E.g. for donor 1, the left lung was placed on the 5th offer and the right was placed on the 10th offer.

**I'm trying to figure out how to code the case for donor 3**:  the left lung is placed on the 3rd offer, but the right is never placed - the match offers continue through 72 offers then just stop.

I'd like the new data to look like:

```
desired_data <- tribble(
  ~donor_id, ~sequence, ~organ_placed,~outcome,
  1, 5, "L","Left Single",
  1, 10, "R","Right Single",
  2, 13, "B","Bilateral",
  3, 4, "L","Left Single",
  3,69,NA,NA,
  3,70,NA,NA,
  3,71,NA,NA,
  3, 72, NA,"Right Discarded"
)
```

I'm thinking it's something like `group_by(donor_id)` and then `slice_max` of `sequence` has `NA` for `organ_placed`, but I need it to code that it's the right lung that's discarded.

```r
data <- data %>%
  mutate(outcome = case_when(
    organ_placed=="L" ~ "Left Single",
    organ_placed=="R" ~ "Right Single",
    organ_placed=="B" ~ "Bilateral",
    **what would go here? to group by donor id and find the maxslice has an NA, 
      and L (or R) already occurred in that donor?**
  ))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: donor 3 left lung is placed on 4th offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do something like this:
Basically in this approach we go simple through all conditions using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(donor_id) %>% 
  mutate(outcome = case_when(organ_placed == "L" ~ "Left Single",
                            organ_placed == "R" ~ "Right Single",
                            organ_placed == "B" ~ "Bilateral",
                            (is.na(organ_placed) & 
                              row_number() == max(row_number())) & 
                              first(organ_placed) == "L" ~ "Right Discarded",
                            (is.na(organ_placed) & 
                               row_number() == max(row_number())) & 
                              first(organ_placed) == "R" ~ "Left Discarded",
                            TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

```
  donor_id sequence organ_placed outcome        
     <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          
1        1        5 L            Left Single    
2        1       10 R            Right Single   
3        2       13 B            Bilateral      
4        3        4 L            Left Single    
5        3       69 NA           NA             
6        3       70 NA           NA             
7        3       71 NA           NA             
8        3       72 NA           Right Discarded
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If in some `donor_id`, only `L`(`R`) appears, then find the position with the maximum `sequence` and fill in `RD`(`LD`).
2. Recode `LD` to `"Left Discarded"` and `RD` to `"Right Discarded"`.

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(.by = donor_id,
         outcome = ifelse(sum(c('L', 'R') %in% organ_placed) == 1 & sequence == max(sequence),
                          paste0(c('L', 'R')[!c('L', 'R') %in% organ_placed], 'D'),
                          organ_placed) %>%
                   case_match("L" ~ "Left Single",
                              "R" ~ "Right Single",
                              "B" ~ "Bilateral",
                              "LD" ~ "Left Discarded",
                              "RD" ~ "Right Discarded"))

# # A tibble: 8 × 4
#   donor_id sequence organ_placed outcome        
#      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>        <chr>          
# 1        1        5 L            Left Single    
# 2        1       10 R            Right Single   
# 3        2       13 B            Bilateral      
# 4        3        4 L            Left Single    
# 5        3       69 NA           NA             
# 6        3       70 NA           NA             
# 7        3       71 NA           NA             
# 8        3       72 NA           Right Discarded
```

***Note:** Setting `.by = donor_id` in `mutate` is equivalent to `group_by(donor_id)` before `mutate` if your `dplyr` version is up to date.*